# Splitting script with getops bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to split code using options with getops, essentially I'd like 1 script to run if 1 option is set, and another script to run if another option is set, see code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A POSIX variable
OPTIND=1         # Reset in case getopts has been used previously in the shell.

# Initialize our own variables:
1=""
2=""
verbose=0


while getopts "h?v:f:m:l:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        exit 0
        ;;
    v)  verbose=1
        ;;
    f)  1=$OPTARG
        ;;
    m)  2=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

for file in $1;
do
        1="$(sed '1d' $1 | awk -F \" '{print $2}')"
        printf "$1\n"
done <"$1"

for file in $2;
do
        2="$(awk '{print $1}' $2 | sort | uniq)"
        printf "$2\n"
done <"$2"
```

So in my code here, if option -f is set with a file, I'd then the for loop starting with "for file in $1" will run. And if -m is set with a file, I'd then the loop starting with "for file in $2" will run.

I'd also like to make it so only -m or -f can be run, i.e. not at the same time.

The command-line usage is: ./script.sh -f file.txt or ./script.sh -m file.txt

How can I set this? (accepting other options other than getops too)

Example file for -f:

```
<blank line>
"b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d","54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b","path/path","output"
"8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7","4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5","path/path2","output2"
"2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91","27d5482eebd075de44389774fce28c69f45c8a75","path/path3","output3"
...
```

Example file for -m:

```
b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d /paths/path
2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91 /paths/path2
```

I'm using awk to pull out the first field for the -f and -m file. The sed command removes the first line () of the file before it extracts the first field out.

Expected Output:

```
b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d
8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7
2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91
b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d
2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91
```

Which I can then use to match against a hashlist file.

Comment: Of all the possible variable names, do you have to use `1` and `2` in `bash`, which have special meaning when used as `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: I used 1 and 2 to try and show script 1 and script 2, not for any other reason really so the variable names could be changed if necessary

Comment: What are your command-line arguments, do mention it above!

Comment: The usage is meant to be ./script.sh -f file.txt or ./script.sh -m file.txt

Comment: So you basically meant, for -f option use `sed` and `-m` use `awk`, also what are you trying to do in `for file in $1;
do...<"$1"` is incorrect

Comment: Yes that's correct, but the files for -f and -m will be difference formats hence why I've split them into 2 separate loops. The for loop is meant to be reading the file into the loop (sorry I'm new to bash scripting)

Comment: Can you give an example for your file and state as part of the question, what you want to do for `-f` option is set and `-m` option is set?

Comment: I hope that update answers your question

Comment: Not yet ;) couple more 1) are you planning to extend options beyond `-f` and `-m`? if not a simple if conditional or a case construct is sufficient. and what are the required outputs for your input files you have provided for those options

Comment: The required output, is the first field, sorted and uniq'ed. The reason I went down the option route is that I plan on matching the first field which i've outputted from the files with another file to see if there are matches, essentially a hash matching script. So ideally, I'd like the input to be: ./script.sh -f file.txt -l matchfile.txt or ./script.sh -m file2.txt -l matchfile.txt. I think trying to simplify my problem ended up making it more difficult to explain xD

Comment: With all the problem around, eventually you want to just get `thisistext` and were you planning to use `sed` and `awk` together for that? That is too much of a work-around for a simple stuff. You don't need anything, just `awk` is sufficient.

Comment: I've simplified the file, the actual files are over 100000 hashes in the 2 different formats

Comment: Am still not clear on your requirement, (correct me if I am wrong) you have file1 and file2 ( for example) you want do some manipulations on both and get a result? is that it/

Comment: In the above script, yes... but I want to do hash matching using the output of the script afterwards. i.e. file1 - format | sort | uniq all the hashes, compare with separate file of hashes for matches, print the output. The locations of each file and the list of hashes can vary, hence why I'd like to parse them in from the command line.

Comment: It looks like all you need is one `Awk` can you a proper example for file1 and file2 contents?

Comment: If this is possible in Awk then that would make my life a lot easier :). I have updated the examples to make them more realistic

Comment: and your expected output? Are those separate files? Also did you miss a `,` in the first two lines after the blank line

Comment: Expected output is the first field of each file, in one output/file, without any quotes or anything around it, I'll update the question with it

Comment: And they are separate files yes :)

Comment: Finally posted the answer, don't forget to mark the answer accepted with a vote, if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* the contents of the two files are as below,

```
cat file1

"b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d","54fd1711209fb1c0781092374132c66e79e2241b","path/path","output"
"8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7","4a0a19218e082a343a1b17e5333409af9d98f0f5","path/path2","output2"
"2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91","27d5482eebd075de44389774fce28c69f45c8a75","path/path3","output3"
```

and the other file being,

```
cat file2
b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d /paths/path
2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91 /paths/path2
```

You can use a single `Awk` as

```
awk 'FNR==NR && NF{gsub(/"/,"",$1); uniqueString[NR]=$1; next}{uniqueString[NR]=$1; next}END{for (i in uniqueString) print uniqueString[i]}' FS="," file1 FS=" " file2
```

which gives

```
b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d
8fa14cdd754f91cc6554c9e71929cce7
2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91
b2f5ff47436671b6e533d8dc3614845d
2510c39011c5be704182423e3a695e91
```

The core logic of `awk` is creating an array `uniqueString` index by `NR`; a special variable in `awk` which keeps track of the line numbers as each lines are processed in the file

The `FNR==NR` parses the first file storing the entries in $1 as a hash-map. Since the values containing double-quotes, it is removed using `gsub()` and the field split `FS` is done by field `,`.

Once all the lines are parsed in `file1`, the following `{..}` part is executed on the second file `file2` again storing the entries of `$1` in the array, but now with field separator set to white-space.

After all the lines are processed, the `END` clause is used to print the lines parsed.